# How do I use Microsoft.Data.Sqlite in a T4 template in VS2017

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2017, t4, .net-standard-2.0

I'm attempting to generate some C# code via my own .tt file in VS2017.
Ideally I want to be able to use an assembly reference to Microsoft.Data.Sqlite but am unable to get a successful transformation.

How do I get a .tt transform to play nicely with the netStandard2.0 dll 
or must I use something like a System.Data.Sqlite .netFramework friendly dll instead?

I've tried adding this extra assembly reference without success:

> <#@ Assembly Name="C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\netstandard.dll" #>

If I add this in an attempt to resolve the netstandard problem it then it produces the following type of errors:

> Compiling transformation: The type 'IDataReader' exists in both 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".generated.cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ Assembly name="$(SolutionDir)PreTemplatingBin\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" #>

…

<#+
    private string GetSubNamespace(string connString)
    {
        return "My.Pretend.Namespace";
    }

    public static SqliteDataReader GetReader(string commandText, string connectionString, out Action cleanup)
    {
        var cnxn = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
        var cmd = new SqliteCommand(commandText, cnxn);

        cnxn.Open();

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        Action cleanup2 = null;
        cleanup2 += () => ((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();
        cleanup2 += () => ((IDisposable)cmd).Dispose();
        cleanup2 += () => ((IDisposable)cnxn).Dispose();

        cleanup = cleanup2;

        return reader;
    }
#>
```

### Expected result:

I would expect to be able to get a .generated.cs will with or without it's own syntax errors.

### Actual result:

DbCommand, DbConnection, DbDataReader transformation errors with the following message(s):

> Compiling transformation: The type 'DbCommand' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

Comment: I've made some progress. <#@ assembly name="NetStandard" #> move things forward but my binary folder or necessary .dlls still seems to be incorrect as I am now seeing the following error: Running transformation: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: This is the 'bait'.  You probably need to add one of the SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_* nuget packages to your platform project.